how to decode ASE on KMM (kotlin Multi-Platform) CCCrypt that have error 4301
i work on KMM project android and iOS
code received data from PHP server that need to decode from AES Cipher
on Android code work but on ios i try to create this code on ios platfrom as kotlin code use objective -c for kmm
when i try use the code on ios not work only work on andrid
my code here on ios
@OptIn(ExperimentalForeignApi::class)
fun iosDecrypt(data: String, secretKey: String): String? {
   val CIPHER_KEY_LEN = kCCKeySizeAES128.toInt()
   //val CIPHER_IV_LEN = 16
   val CIPHER_ALGORITHM = kCCAlgorithmAES128
   val CIPHER_OPTIONS = kCCOptionPKCS7Padding
   var key = secretKey
   try {
       if (key.length < CIPHER_KEY_LEN) {
           val numPad: Int = CIPHER_KEY_LEN - key.length
           for (i in 0 until numPad) {key += "0"
           }
       } else if (key.length > CIPHER_KEY_LEN) {
           key = key.substring(0, CIPHER_KEY_LEN)
       }


       val parts = data.split(":")
       val encryptedData = parts[0].base64Decoded.toByteArray().toNSData()//decodeBase64(parts[0])
       val ivData =parts[1].base64Decoded.toByteArray().toNSData()// decodeBase64(parts[1])
       println("iv = $ivData")
       val keyDataByte = key.toByteArray(Charsets.ISO_8859_1)
       println("keyDataByte :${keyDataByte.contentToString() }, bytes :${keyDataByte.size}")
       val keyData = keyDataByte.toNSData()
       println("keyData :$keyData , bytes :${keyData.length}")
       val decryptedData = NSMutableData()
       println("decryptedData:$decryptedData")


       memScoped { // Use memScoped for memory allocation
           val numBytesDecrypted = alloc<size_tVar>()


           val status = CCCrypt(
               kCCDecrypt,
               CIPHER_ALGORITHM,
               CIPHER_OPTIONS,
               keyData.bytes,
               kCCKeySizeAES128.toULong(),
               ivData.bytes,
               encryptedData.bytes,
               (encryptedData.length.convert() ?: 0).toULong(),
               decryptedData.mutableBytes,
               decryptedData.length.convert(),
               numBytesDecrypted.ptr
           )
           if (status == kCCSuccess) {
               decryptedData.setLength( numBytesDecrypted.value.toULong())
               return decryptedData.toString()
           } else {
               println("Decryption failed with status: $status")
               return null
           }
       }
   } catch (ex: Exception) {
       ex.printStackTrace()
   }
   return null
}


@OptIn(ExperimentalForeignApi::class, BetaInteropApi::class)
fun ByteArray.toNSData(): NSData {
   memScoped {
       val data = this@toNSData
       val pointer = data.usePinned {
           it.addressOf(0)
       }
       return NSData.create(bytes = pointer, length = data.size.toULong())
   }
}

there out Decryption failed with  status :4301
this code build i don't know where the problem of code
are there can other way to decode
iv and key and data i had sure on it be same of on android debug
and sure from decode64 for both

at last i found very easy way to do decrypt all platform without expect/actual
we need to use this library Krypto
setup :
file libs.versions.toml
krypto = "4.0.10"
krypto = { module = "com.soywiz.korlibs.krypto:krypto", version.ref = "krypto" }

on build,gradle.kt
 commonMain.dependencies {
            implementation(libs.krypto)
}

and this code
fun decrypt(data: String,secretKey:String): String? {
    val CIPHER_KEY_LEN= 16
    var key = secretKey
    if (key.length < CIPHER_KEY_LEN) {
        val numPad: Int = CIPHER_KEY_LEN - key.length
        for (i in 0 until numPad) {
            key += "0" //0 pad to len 16 bytes
        }
    } else if (key.length > CIPHER_KEY_LEN) {
        key = key.substring(0, CIPHER_KEY_LEN) //truncate to 16 bytes
    }
    val parts = data.split(":").toTypedArray()
    val encData = parts[0].decodeBase64Bytes()
    val iv = parts[1].decodeBase64Bytes()
    val sKeySpec = key.toByteArray(charset("ISO-8859-1"))
    try{
        val dec = AES.decryptAesCbc(encData, sKeySpec, iv, Padding.PKCS7Padding) /// only this line to decrypt and no all on ios perform
        return dec.decodeToString()
    }
    catch (e:Exception)
    {
        e.printStackTrace()
        return null
    }

}

